# Displaying a custom post from a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I made a custom taxonomy:

```
function project_register_taxonomy(){

$singular = 'Project Categories';
$plural = 'Projects Categories';
$slug = str_replace( ' ', '_', strtolower( $singular ) );
$labels = array(
        'name'                       => $plural,
        'singular_name'              => $singular,
        'search_items'               => 'Search ' . $plural,
        'popular_items'              => 'Popular ' . $plural,
        'all_items'                  => 'All ' . $plural,
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit ' . $singular,
        'update_item'                => 'Update ' . $singular,
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New ' . $singular,
        'new_item_name'              => 'New ' . $singular . ' Name',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate ' . $plural . ' with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove ' . $plural,
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used ' . $plural,
        'not_found'                  => 'No ' . $plural . ' found.',
        'menu_name'                  => $plural,
);
$args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => $$slug ),
);

register_taxonomy ('Project Categories','projects', $args);
}

add_action( 'init', 'project_register_taxonomy');
```

And registered it to a custom post:

```
function create_galblock() {

register_post_type( 'projects',
        // CPT Options
        array(
                'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
                        'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
                ),

                'taxonomies' => array('category'),

                'description' => 'Projects by Almog',
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
                'supports' => array( 'title','editor', 'thumbnail')
        )
);
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_galblock' );
```

I need to get the post title, post thumbnail and content of custom post 'projects' of the custom taxonomy 'Project Categories'.

This is my code for trying to achieve at least the content:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'projects',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'Projects Categories',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => '8'
    )
)
 );
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
 //content
 endwhile;
 ?>
```

Obviously it doesn't return the custom posts from the custom taxonomy.

Comment: the `taxonomy` should be a slug. So in your case `projects` if I'm not mistaken. Also where do you want to show this query?

Comment: You mean, how? and like nano said, the $taxonomy is project_categories from what I can tell

Comment: Yeah, like nano suggested `register_taxonomy ('project_categories','projects', $args);` Then like he suggested should work.

Comment: It does not unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I got this to work:

```
function project_register_taxonomy(){

    $singular = 'Project Categories';
    $plural = 'Projects Categories';
    $slug = str_replace( ' ', '_', strtolower( $singular ) );
    $labels = array(
            'name'                       => $plural,
            'singular_name'              => $singular,
            'search_items'               => 'Search ' . $plural,
            'popular_items'              => 'Popular ' . $plural,
            'all_items'                  => 'All ' . $plural,
            'parent_item'                => null,
            'parent_item_colon'          => null,
            'edit_item'                  => 'Edit ' . $singular,
            'update_item'                => 'Update ' . $singular,
            'add_new_item'               => 'Add New ' . $singular,
            'new_item_name'              => 'New ' . $singular . ' Name',
            'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate ' . $plural . ' with commas',
            'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove ' . $plural,
            'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used ' . $plural,
            'not_found'                  => 'No ' . $plural . ' found.',
            'menu_name'                  => $plural,
    );
    $args = array(
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_admin_column'     => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var'             => true,
            'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => $slug ),
    );

    register_taxonomy ('project_categories','projects', $args);
}

add_action( 'init', 'project_register_taxonomy');


function create_galblock() {

    register_post_type( 'projects',
            // CPT Options
            array(
                    'labels' => array(
                            'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
                            'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
                    ),

                    'taxonomies' => array('category'),

                    'description' => 'Projects by Almog',
                    'public' => true,
                    'has_archive' => true,
                    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
                    'supports' => array( 'title','editor', 'thumbnail')
            )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_galblock' );
```

And I created a test page using `page-projects.php` template that looks like this

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying project pages
 * Template Name: Projects Page
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<h3>Projects</h3>
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php

        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'projects',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query'      => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'project_categories',
                    'field'    => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                    'terms'    => 61,
                )
            )
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            $the_query->the_post();

            echo the_title();

        endwhile;
        ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->

</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now I added a test project category, which had `tag_id` 61 (when you hover over it you can see it), and a test post in that category.

[image]

And it showed that post just fine. now if you leave out the `fields` and `terms` in your `tax_query`, this won't work. But I'd just leave that out in the first place and get all the projects out (and figure out the sorting later).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually got it to work, what's the difference between term_taxonomy_id and term_id?

Comment: Well I think it has to do with how the terms and taxonomies are written in WordPress database. `term_id` is located in the terms table, and `term_taxonomy_id` links the taxonomy and the term (with 1-1 correspondence).

Comment: What if I have a post that is associated with two categories and I want to have it displayed in both of the pages? (every page have a template for a category)

Comment: Well if it is associated with both, it should appear on both pages, just like regular categories do.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy):

> **$taxonomy**: (string) (required) The name of the taxonomy. Name should ***only contain lowercase letters and the underscore character***, and not be more than 32 characters long (database structure restriction).

You specified *Project Categories* which won't be good as you can see above.

```
register_taxonomy ('project_categories','projects', $args);
```

**Update:**

You also have to modify your query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'projects_categories',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => '8'
        )
    )
);
```

Notice the change in the `tax_query`:

`taxonomy` should be `projects_categories`

`field` should be `term_id`

Comment: No display... what I want to do is display the custom post project from the category that is named 'Renovation' that it's id is 8 from the custom taxonomy 'projects_categories', does my code with your correction achieves that?

Comment: I got the id=8 from the bottom console, it says tag_id=8, I guess that's the problem?

Comment: Thanks alot for your time!